# How to fix height for a responsive website for mobile website?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, frontend, mobile-website

Am building a responsive website, for which am building it to fit on any mobile device (screen).

Now, with breakpoints the widths are adjusted to so and so mobile screens based on the number of breakpoints i use / specify. But the issue is am not able to fix the height, so to adjust the height to 100% to any mobile device. Could i please know how do i do that?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this works for [modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units):

```
html,
body {
    height:auto!important;
    min-height:100vh;
}
```

If you need to support older browsers, you'll need to do something like this:

```
html,
body {
    height:100%;
}

#wrapping-div {
    height:auto!important;
    min-height:100%;
}
```

And that should suffice, but notice the need for a wrapping div in that case.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, tried the one with #wrapping-div did not work though for the div alone.

Comment: Can you provide a more detailed explanation than "it didn't work"? Not a lot to go on.

Comment: @PlantTheldea: Here is the jsfiddle i was talking about.

http://jsfiddle.net/s5o148ot/

Now the first section has height of pixel 872px and rest of the section height is 900px. Now since this is in pixel it is fixed. But this height (bottom of the section) should fit on any screen. Please let me know if you need any more explanation.

Comment: so I completely misunderstood your statement about wanting 100% height, I see what you're going for here. Assuming the use of `vh` will not work (since you dismissed it prior, even though it would give you exactly what you want), you should use JS to set the height of your "wrap all" container to an explicit height, then all the children pages would simply be set to `height:100%`, or even `height:inherit`. best i got for ya

Comment: Okay, have not done that before, will look for it online though, thank you.